# How to reverse the order of the columns in google sheet after extracting the data from another sheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So I extracted data from one google sheets to another google sheet using google sheets API successfully. Now i want to reverse the order of the columns, for example want column A with K, B with J, and for on. This is my code for now:

```
function authenticate() {
return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
.signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"})
.then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
      function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
function loadClient() {
gapi.client.setApiKey("");
.then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
          function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
function execute() {
return gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.sheets.copyTo({
  "spreadsheetId": "",
  "sheetId": ,

 "resource": {
    "destinationSpreadsheetId": ""
  }
})
.then(function(response) {
            // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
            console.log("Response", response);
          },
          function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
("client:auth2", function() {
gapi.auth2.init({client_id: ""});
});
```

How can I edit this code to put the columns in reverse order using code? Here is a link to my spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BJ0Y8viJE8a2jU6rfNGuNp5n1jwQauee1p9-PxuuVHE/edit#gid=533169457

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal and current situation as follows.

- You want to put the values from the source sheet to the destination sheet by selecting the specific columns from the source sheet using googleapis for Javascript.

  - In your case, as a sample, you want to select the columns "A,K,B,J" from the source sheet and put them to the destination sheet.
- You have already been get and put values for Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API using your current script.

#### Modification points:

- In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose the following flow.

  1. Retrieve the values from the source sheet using spreadsheets.values.get.
  2. Extract the specific columns from the retrieved values.
  3. Put the extracted values to the destination sheet using spreadsheets.values.update.

When this flow is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set the variables of `spreadsheetId`, `sourceSheetName`, `destinationSheetName` and `extractColumns`.

```
const spreadsheetId = "###";
const sourceSheetName = "###";
const destinationSheetName = "###";
const extractColumns = [1, 11, 2, 10];  // "A,K,B,J" in order.

const transpose = (ar) => ar[0].map((_, i) => ar.map(r => r[i]));
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
  range: sourceSheetName
}).then((res)=>{
  const transposedValues = transpose(res.result.values);
  const extractedColumns = extractColumns.map(c => transposedValues[c - 1]);
  const resultValues = transpose(extractedColumns);
  gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
    spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId,
    range: destinationSheetName,
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED"
  }, {
    values: resultValues
  }).then((r) => {
    console.log(res.result.values)
  }, function(er) {
    console.error(er.result.error.message);
  })
}, function(err) {
  console.error(err.result.error.message);
});
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

Comment: When I tried this I got a reference error referring to the const extract columns saying they are not defined how would i fix this issue?

Comment: @craigreska Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `When I tried this I got a reference error referring to the const extract columns saying they are not defined how would i fix this issue?`, unfortunately, in my environment, I could confirm that the proposed script worked. So I proposed it. So I cannot replicate your situation. I apologize for this. But I would like to resolve your issue. So can you provide the detail information for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: <https://script.google.com/d/1Pxeyd_beYR82ezT0RNaJBw5s9F0rNUKVKXb-hTbcrOg2ORRQJaOE5kgs/edit?mid=ACjPJvHNLyo3V5r4P1KLyRNd3QBptJ2r0O9gIBjUVmv6liIld-FVyrdQ-kSGw40v0DK45iYODZhWmGIKL0rlwdrnOo5IA6aEbhU02TE1SmS9915NU3YcvbMfVaPLgkO06f6UAnFdzloOB6Q&uiv=2>

Comment: @craigreska Thank you for replying. I will check it.

Comment: @craigreska In your script, what is `k,j,i,h,,F,E,D,C,B,A` of `const extractColumns = [k,j,i,h,,F,E,D,C,B,A];`?

Comment: Those are my columns to extract and I changed them to be in the write order and they are all capitalized now

Comment: @craigreska Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Those are my columns to extract and I changed them to be in the write order and they are all capitalized now`. If `const extractColumns = [k,j,i,h,,F,E,D,C,B,A];` is used, all values of `k,j,i,h,,F,E,D,C,B,A` are required to be the variables. In my proposal script, the column number is used. For example, "A,K,B,J" in order is `[1, 11, 2, 10]`. How about this?

Comment: That worked, but now i get that the gapi.client.sheets part causes a reference error